# How to delete a primary key that exists as a composite key in another

Tags: php, html, database

I am trying to delete an item by it's ID from items table, but it's ID exists in another table as a composite key.

This is the delete item PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST["deleteItem"])){
       try{
             $itemID = $_POST['itemID'];
        
        require('connection.php');
        $sql=$db->exec("DELETE FROM cart c INNER JOIN wishlist w INNER JOIN items i WHERE c.iid=w.iid AND w.iid=i.item_id AND i.item_id='$itemID'");
            if($sql==1)
            {
            header('location:index.php');
            }
            else{
                echo "NotDeleted";
            } 
        
          $db=null;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
        }
        }
```

And this is the Error message showed up to me:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3gSN.png)

And this is the items table that I want to delete the item_id from it:
[Items Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWdr3.png)

This is cart and wishlist table that item_id exist in them as a composite key:
[cart and wishlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMLbB.png)
[cart and wishlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8taKu.png)

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Comment: Ok i can change it later but do you know how to fix the sql query ?

Comment: If you're getting a syntax error, look up the proper syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html#idm45748476822208

Comment: I did the same but still having same error do you have another solution? + I updated the SQL statement

Comment: I would recommend ansi style which uses the keyword `ON` to make it more clear how the joins are accomplished, rather than stuffing them willy-nilly into the`WHERE` clause. Also, if you have foreign key. constraints, you may have to delete the composite rows first.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to delete the composite key first?

Comment: that’s *if* it has a constraint. I don’t know your schema, but the delete query would also use itemID. Proceed with caution ;)

Comment: I put a screenshot of my tables, where in items table item_id exists as a primary key, and in wishilist and cart table the item_id (iid) exists as a foreign key as well as a composite primary key with other fields in the tables, so what i ant to do is to delete a specific item id so I tried many ways but they didn't work, do you know how to delete it?